# Shared folder visibile but not accessibile

Tags: nautilus

I installed Nautilus and share a folder.

I'm able to see my folder via Windows or Android, but when I try to open it I get an error (unable to access, no permissions). My goal is to have a shared folder to send my scan directly from my printer.

I checked both the options about permissions, but it's still not working.

[image: Screen]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using as all version already have Nautilus no need to install it.

Comment: 22.10. I installed Nautilus maually because after this I cannot see the share option on my right click.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand. 22.10 already had that app by default.

Comment: My goal is to have a shared folder in which my printer will send the scan. So basically I nedd an accessibile folder on my network. I didn't have the "share" on my right click. So I installed Nautilus and it appears. I share a folder settings all permissions. I'm able to see it on my Windows PC but if I try to access to it i get an "access denied" message.